# How to sort without lambda function

Tags: python, function, sorting, lambda

I am beginner in Python.

I wrote the code because I wanted to try sorting using the lambda function without a function.

I tried to sort the list by receiving the length of a, but this error occurred.

I interpreted the words of the error below to mean that it must be in the form of a list.

Is that correct?

```
strings = ['bob', 'charles', 'alexander3', 'teddy']

for i in strings:
    a = len(i) # 3 7 10 5
    a.sort() 
print(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [53], in <cell line: 3>()
      3 for i in strings:
      4     a = len(i)
----> 5     a.sort()
      6     print(a)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

And this is the code I modified accordingly.
Is this way right?

```
strings = ['bob', 'charles', 'alexander3', 'teddy']

b = []
for i in strings:
    a = len(i)
    b.append(a)
print(b)
```

However, I need to make a code that outputs the corresponding letter to see if I took the wrong direction, but I'm not doing it well.

```
strings = ['bob', 'charles', 'alexander3', 'teddy']

strings.sort(key=lambda x:len(x))
print(strings)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

['bob', 'teddy', 'charles', 'alexander3']
```

I would like to reproduce this code without a lambda function. How can I do this? I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: If you want to sort a list by some criteria other than simply comparing the elements, you *have* to use `.sort()`'s `key=` parameter, which has to be a callable object of some sort.  It could be a normal `def` function, or an instance of a class with a `__call__()` method, but `lambda` is perfect for a tiny function like this, used at a single point in your program.  Why do you feel the need to avoid its use?

Comment: You could just do `strings.sort(key=len)`.  Wrapping `len` in a lambda expression that just calls `len` with the exact same arguments is unnecessary; you use a lambda to define a new function, and `len` is *already a function that does exactly what you want*.

Answer (score 0):

```
strings = ['bob', 'charles', 'alexander3', 'teddy']
sorted(strings,key=len) 

#['bob', 'teddy', 'charles', 'alexander3']
```

will do without lambda function

*Note: It will return a new list*

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you really don't want to use a sorting function, you can twist things around to use the default sorting:

```
strings = ['bob', 'charles', 'alexander3', 'teddy']
len_with_strings = [(len(w), w) for w in strings]
sorted_strings = [b for a,b in sorted(len_with_strings)]
```